# Prove or disprove L is regular

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

There is question in one of my exercise but I couldn't prove or disprove anything about it.
This is language $L$ which is introduced with grammar:
$$S \to 0S1 | 1S0 | AA$$
$$A \to 0A | \lambda|A1$$

My explanation and work:
I know that we can prove with **pumping lemma** that a language is not regular.
I know that if $L_1 \subset L_2$ and $L_2$ is regular, then $L_1$ maybe regular or not so in this example, $0^n1^n \subset L$ but we can't say that this language is not regular.
next, I think that $L$ is regular because grammar $A$ can produce anything but after a little try, I found that $A = 0^*1^*$ and $110101$ is not a part of language, so it can not be $(1 | 0)^*$ which is regular.
at this point, I don't know is it regular, or not. $S$ grammar can produce strings which has equal 0 and 1 at the start and end, but maybe $A$ grammar can produce something that make language regular.
Is it possible to help me? can you give me any idea?

#### Idea (from comment):

if we say that $L$ is regular, then we get intersection of it and $0^*1010101^*$.
for accept a string in this language, there is two state.

1) not equal number of $0$ and $1$ at the start and end of string:
suppose number is form of $0^n1010101^{n+k}$ for $k \gt 0$ (we can prove same for $0$). use $S \to 0S1$ to create $0$ at the start and $1$ end, after some level we get to $0^nS1^n$ but we can't use any $S \to 0S1$ or $S \to 1S0$ anymore so we must use $S \to AA$ and $A = 0^*1^*$ and we can't match string. we couldn't construct it if we start with $S \to AA$. 
so $L$ can't produce this kind of strings.

2) equal number of $0$ and $1$ at the start and end of string:
now our string is form of $0^n1010101^n$ and we can construct it with only $S \to 0S1|1S0$.

so intersection of $L$ and $0^*1010101^*$ is $0^n1010101^n$ which is easy to prove that is not regular. so our hypothesis is not correct and $L$ is not regular.

Thanks for idea. Is it true?

Comment: Hint: intersect your language with $0^*1010101^*$. (Simpler examples might be possible.)

Comment: When you say $\lambda$, did you mean $\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes. $\lambda$ means $\epsilon$.

Comment: I add a way. is it true?

Comment: Yes, I think that this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grammar generates the following language:
$$
L = \{ w0^*1^*0^*1^*\bar{w}^R : w \in \{0,1\}^* \},
$$
where $\bar{w}$ is obtained from $w$ by switching 0s and 1s. Consider now $L' = L \cap 0^*1010101^*$. It is not hard to check that $L$ contains all words of the form $0^n1010101^n$ (take $w = 0^n1$ and $0101 \in 0^*1^*0^*1^*$). Conversely, if $0^n1010101^m \in L'$ and $n \neq m$, say $n > m$, then the decomposition $0^n1010101^m = wx\bar{w}^R$, where $x \in 0^*1^*0^*1^*$, must satisfy that $\bar{w}^R = 1^k$ for some $k \leq m$; but then $x = 0^{n-k}1010101^{m-k} \notin 0^*1^*0^*1^*$. We conclude that
$$
L' := L \cap 0^*1010101^* = \{ 0^n1010101^n : n \geq 0 \}.
$$
It is not hard to check that $L'$ is not regular (for example, the words $0^n$ are pairwise inequivalent), and so $L$ also isn't regular.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your reasoning in the "idea from the comments":

Note that for any positive integers $n$ and $m$, $0^n1010101^m$ is not in $L$ if $m > n$, and is in $L$ if $n = m$. (using your "1" and "2" statements)

Therefore, the strings $0^{n}101010$ for all positive integers $n$ are in distinct equivalence classes as used in the Myhill-Nerode theorem, and therefore $L$ is not regular.